# Cloudera install agent issue

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed cm6 already, and want to install cloudera manager agent from custom repository and CDH6 with using packages.
(I work with only one host)
I have files for cloudera manager agent in directory /cloudera/cloudera-repo/cm6/6.0.1  and for CDH6 in directory /cloudera/cloudera-repo/cdh6/6.0.1

My steps for Cloudera Manager Agent:

```
 Custom repository -> choose http://ip_addr/cloudera/cloudera-repo/cm6/6.0.1
```

For CDH and other software:

```
 Install Method -> Use Packages 
 CDH Version -> CDH6 
 CDH Minor Version -> choose http://ip_addr/cloudera/cloudera-repo/cdh6/6.0.1
```

And on page Install Agents I have such error:

> Failed to copy installation files
>   /tmp/scm_prepare_node.xpsM8dvM
>   Connection refused (Connection refused)

I have same error even when I specify empty directories. Why?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems that you have not provided proper credentials to connect to your host. The ssh credentials seems to be incorrect. If you are sure, ssh credentials are fine, then it is a firewall issue. You need to make sure all the required ports are enabled and no blocker is there for cloudera to install the agent.